# VBA to divide cell range in 3

Tags: excel, vba

has anyone know a script in vba to divide (dont know if is the right word sorry, non native english excel user) a group of cells in 3 to asign them a value...for example i have this : column a with cells  from a2 to a121...in column b i want that the first 40 cells have name x , the second 40 cells name y and the third 40 name z.
I tried with lastrow and division to no success

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```
Sub test()
cnt = 3
Set rg = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
r = Application.RoundDown(rg.Rows.Count / cnt, 0)
Set oStart = rg.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 1)
    For i = 1 To cnt
        oStart.Resize(r, 1).Value = InputBox("blablabla")
        Set oStart = oStart.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

The code count how many rows (with value) are there from cell A2 to the last row. If for example there are 41 rows, then it will divide it by 3. The result is 13. Then it will ask you for 3 times to input the name you want. The last two rows (41 - [13 x 3] = 2) will not have a name from you.